# ASP.NET получить производительность сравнимую с php методом mssql_query( $query )

Tags: asp.net

Код на PHP:

```php
...
$query = "exec DBNAME.dbo.STOREDProcedureNAME ".$params."";
$result = mssql_query( $query ); 
...
```

Код на ASP.NET:

```cs
...
using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigAppSettings.Current.DBLink)) { using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("STOREDProcedureName, SqlCon)) { SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0; SqlCon.Open(); SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCmd); SqlParameterCollection Param = SqlCmd.Parameters;
..here stored procedure parameters set ... 
SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(); grid.DataSource = reader; grid.DataBind(); } } 
...
```

Поиски в интернете дали [следующее](https://sourceforge.net/p/care2002/mailman/attachment/20030626122118.89487.qmail@web40013.mail.yahoo.com/1/):

> ASP will probably never be as fast as PHP. ASP is built on a COM-based architecture.When he writes to the client, he's calling the Response COM object's Write method. When he accesses a database, he uses another COM object to do so. When he accesses the file system, another COM object is called. All this COM overhead adds up and slows things down. In PHP modules, everything runs in PHP's memory space. This means that PHP code will run faster because there is no overhead of communicating with different COM objects in different processes.
>
> The following benchmark, where we execute a Select statement 40 times on Microsoft SQL Server 7 using PHP's MSSQL7 extension, PHP's ODBC extension and COM, will show you what I mean:When we access the database using PHP's ODBC extension, it's 9.54 secs. Using the COM interface to connect to ODBC adds a 80% overhead (17.28 secs) to ODBC. OLEDB is Microsoft's high speed COM technology for accessing databases. It is faster than ODBC, but when we use the PHP MSSQL extension we get a 200% increase in performance. So just tell a ASP programmer: No COM more speed.

Суть проблемы следующая:одна и та-же хранимая процедура выполняется одинаково долго при её вызове и из СКУЛ студии и из приложения на ASP.NET.
А при её вызове из PHP - время получения результатов сокращается в 2-2.5 раза.

Процедура трудоёмкая. Всё что можно уже оптимизировано.
Время выполнения - 40-45 секунд из студии и ASP.NET приложения и 15-20 секунд при вызове из php.

У кого-нибудь был опыт получения в ASP.NET такой-же скорости выполнения sql запросов, как в PHP?

Comment: откуда цитата про ASP?

Comment: [ссылка](https://sourceforge.net/p/care2002/mailman/attachment/20030626122118.89487.qmail@web40013.mail.yahoo.com/1/)

Comment: @Ultimat, Вас не смущает, что цитата относится к 2000-му году, когда как релиз ASP.NET состоялся в 2002 году? И да, речь в статье идет именно о ASP как [Active Server Pages](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages), которые писались с использованием JS или VB, которые как раз постоянно дергали COM объекты через ActiveX.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, но к сожалению  -это единственная информация, которую удалось найти по поводу таких странных затыкав с производительностью. И, что интересно, то моя ситуация со 100% точностью совпадает с описанной. На php получаю прирост производительности в 2-2.5 раза.

Comment: @Ultimat, все зависит от конкретного кода. Без него абсолютно ничего нельзя сказать. Нужно замерять на что конкретно тратится время

Comment: код слишком громоздский и закрытый ;( не могу приводить его тут. В нём происходит жуткая агрегация, доставшаяся "по наследству", которая уже оптимизирована - ранее код отрабатывал порядка 3 минут при вызове из СКУЛ студии и порядка 1.5 минут при вызове из php.

Comment: @Ultimat, хорошо, Вы замеряли скорость выполнения строки кода  `SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()` без всего лишнего? А то я вижу тут еще кусок привязки приведен, который меня смущает.

Comment: так замерь, на что уходит время: сколько на выполнение процедуры, сколько на запрос, сколько на отдачу, сколько на серверную часть

Comment: @AlexKrass, как вариант, php выплевывает по одной строчке и отрисовывает, а asp ждет все и выплевывает одним куском

Comment: Да, приведённые цыфры - это замеры только самого выполнения, без привязки полученных данных к гриду.

Comment: на сколько я могу судить, то и после mssql_query( $query ) и после ExecuteReader() - данные получены целиком.

Comment: _Да, приведённые цыфры - это замеры только самого выполнения,_ добавь пример как ты замерял

Comment: DateTime start = DateTime.Now;SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("Time Elapsed : " + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

Comment: $start = microtime(true); ...запрос...
echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.(microtime(true) - $start).' сек.';

Comment: Я бы еще попробовал из ASP.NET вызвать процедуру не как явно хранимую, а как в PHP прямым запросом. Мало ли это что-то даст. И на будущее, есть такая вещь как [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: пробовал делать запрос из ASP.NET через EXEC - результат тот-же. Про Stopwatch знаю, но в данном конкретном случае замерялось так - исторически сложилось ))))

Comment: Так-же пробовал работать из ASP.NET не через SQLClient, а через OLEDB, ODBC и даже через DAO и драйвера от dbforge - результат всё те-же 40 секунд +/- 1-2 секунды

Comment: Для того чтобы отредактировать вопрос используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом